# Adding CustomBusinessHour to DateTimeIndex in vectorized manner

Tags: pandas, numpy, optimization, time-series, vectorization

Suppose I have a `DateTimeIndex` which I wish to add a `CustomBusinessHour` to. My `CustomBusinessHour` keeps indexes the same that fall between 0900 and 2000 on the same day, it moves indexes that fall between 0000 and 0900 to 0900 the same day, and moves indexes after 2000 to 0900 the next business day; taking into account some holidays.

The following code works as I intend

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessHour


idxs = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-08-14 21:54:00', '2018-08-28 21:48:00',
               '2018-10-02 23:13:00', '2019-06-26 10:59:00'])

custom_days = CustomBusinessHour(
                holidays=[pd.Timestamp("2019/01/01"),
                          pd.Timestamp("2018/12/25"),
                          pd.Timestamp("2018/12/26")],
                weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri',
                start="09:00", end="20:00")

moved_idx = idxs + 0*custom_days
```

However, I get the following warning

> PerformanceWarning: Non-vectorized DateOffset being applied to Series
>   or DatetimeIndex

How can I convert `custom_days` to a `numpy` array to add this to `idxs` in a vectorized manner to remove this warning?